# Drawing a finite state machine in a web application

Tags: angularjs, npm, state-machine, sigma.js

The following link gives an excellent explanation of what the core logic of my application will be:

[Code Golf: Finite-state machine!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661818/code-golf-finite-state-machine)

I'm looking to use this logic to actually draw finite state machines on my web app, via some library, very similarly to the image in the above link. I've spent several hours trying to make progress with the sigma graph library, but I haven't had much luck.

Here's the sigma documentation: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki

Is there an existing library that would be a good fit for this kind of drawing problem? I'm willing to go quite out of my way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully sure if this will answer your question but have you looked into [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/)?  I'm not sure if it has the functionality you are looking for but it may help in some way.